# Executing a query on geomesa cassandra datastore using JAVA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, cql, geomesa

i have been following the geomesa cassandra quickstart tutrorila https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-cassandra.html
and now i am build a spring boot api to query on the imported table,
in the example code i find CQL filter which acts as the WHERE part in the normal sql query:

```
new Query(getTypeName(), ECQL.toFilter( "Actor2CountryCode LIKE 'AU'" ))
```

but i cant figure out how to write the SELECT FROM part using this ECQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not generally feasible to query GeoMesa raw data directly - you should instead use the GeoTools API and GeoTools ECQL filters (not Cassandra CQL).

To see what select statements are generated from a given GeoTools query, you can use the `getQueryPlan` method as described in the GeoMesa [documentation](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/query_planning.html#explaining-query-plans). This will return an instance of `CassandraQueryPlan` which has a reference to the `statements` to execute (see [here](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/geomesa_2.11-2.1.0/geomesa-cassandra/geomesa-cassandra-datastore/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/cassandra/data/CassandraQueryPlan.scala#L23)). Note that there may be a secondary filter applied on the results of the statements, defined as `clientSideFilter` in the query plan.

Comment: is there any examples of this ?

Comment: also how to perform any aggregation function like sum or count on specific field ?

Comment: For aggregation functions, you can either use our native [stats API](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/analytic_queries.html#statistical-queries) or [Spark](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/providers.html#geotools-rdd-provider)

Comment: I don't believe that there are any examples of using a query plan directly, as it's not a standard use case. You can look at the source code to see how they are used internally.